# Does Wolkenkit event-sourcing have a scheduler?

Tags: node.js, domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing, wolkenkit

I'd like to schedule time-triggered actions to fire off events at both intervals and specific times. This would be useful if I needed to say, change the aggregate state with some events like `meetingStarted` and `meetingEnded` based on something like a `start_at` and `end_at` for a room-booking service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, [wolkenkit](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit) does *not* have a scheduler like this. Adding this is on the roadmap, but currently it's not yet implemented.

*Please note that I am one of the developers of wolkenkit, so please take my answer with a grain of salt.*