# How do I realize repetitive tasks in wolkenkit?

Tags: wolkenkit

What would be the best way to implement repetitive tasks in wolkenkit?
Let's say I want to import calendar events on a daily basis or fetch data from a server to update some kind of aggregate. What would be the best practice here?

I thought about setting up a timer somewhere that sends commands on a regular basis so that the aggregate's data can be updated, but I am not quite sure about where to put the timer. After searching a bit online I am unsure if this is something I am not supposed to do at all, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there is no built-in mechanism to handle time based scheduling. But you can create a node script that gets data from a server and then uses the client SDK to send commands in order to update aggregates. You can use some kind of scheduling mechanism to run it repetitively, e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

Comment: I think this is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49618467/does-wolkenkit-event-sourcing-have-a-scheduler/49619190#49619190, although I wanted to ask more specifically. For now, I will have one _master-client_ handle such things, just as you said.

Comment: This is exactly the problem: Using a module such as node-cron you don't get a reliable distributed timer – if the process running node-cron crashes, the timers won't run for the time it takes the process to restart. This is why it's on the roadmap, to get a really reliable version here. Right now, we don't have anything for that. If you would like to discuss ideas, feel free to do so in the wolkenkit Slack (http://slackin.wolkenkit.io).